# What is the syntax for calling a base class's value constructor with a base class pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

The base class has a value constructor that takes in arguments. It has not default constructor.

The following uses a `base` class pointer that it set equal to the address of some `derived` class object on the heap. This explicitly calls the value constructor of `derived`. Is there a way to explicitly call the value constructor of `base` in this line? I understand an alternative is you can have the derived class constructor call the base class constructor.

`base *ptr = new derived(args);`

Comment: No, C++ does not work this way. Only the constructor of the derived class calls the constructor of the base class. The "alternative" which you mentioned is the only way how C++ works.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think he can use it by using `using Base::Base;` but here the two constructors have one arg, so a new ambiguity.

Comment: @asmmo in that situation the derived constructor still hides the base, if they have exactly the same signature  (using-declaration for member functions works differently to block-scope using-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

You can  explicitly call the value constructor of `base` in your line as follows (but note that the lists of the parameters differ)

```
   #include<iostream>

    class Base{

    public:
        Base(int arg){std::cout<<"\nBase constructor";}
        Base()=default;
        virtual ~Base(){}
    };

    class Derived:public Base{
    public:
        Derived(double arg){
            std::cout<<"\nDerived constructor";
        }
        using Base::Base;//This is the key for the answer

    };


    int main(){

        Base* derivedPtr1 {new Derived{0.2}};//calls derived ctor
        Base* derivedPtr2 {new Derived{2}};//calls base ctor
        delete derivedPtr2;
        delete derivedPtr1;

    }
```

Anothe code where there is no default ctor

```
#include<iostream>

class Base{

public:
    Base(int arg){std::cout<<"\nBase constructor";}
    virtual ~Base(){}

};

class Derived:public Base{
int k{};
public:
    Derived(double arg):Base(2){
        std::cout<<"\nDerived constructor";
    }
    using Base::Base;
    Derived()=default;
    ~Derived(){std::cout<<"\nDerived destructor";}

};


int main(){

    Base* derivedPtr1 {new Derived{0.2}};
    Base* derivedPtr2 {new Derived{2}};
    delete derivedPtr2;
    delete derivedPtr1;

}
```

Comment: Interesting what if the parameters for both `Base` & `Derived` constructors were `int a`? How would the program decide which one to call? And would you be able to explicitly tell the program which one to call?

Comment: @TedLyngmo OP appears to be asking for dynamic allocation

Comment: @David If `Derived` makes an overload with the same signature, that will hide the function in the base class, so if you instantiate a `Derived`, it will use `Derived`'s constructor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, that would be a good idea. (BTW deleting the base pointer is undefined behaviour otherwise, not necessarily "only the base class destructor will be called").

Comment: Sorry I ffocused to introduce `using` only @TedLyngmo

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm focussing on the concept, then the OP can modify the code as he want. Thanks!